# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user - OVH Eloquent

Tags: eloquent

For a project I use Slim 3 - Twig and Eloquent. On development mode, all works perfectly, but on production, hosted in the OVH shared server, I can't access to the database.

I'm hundred percent sure of credentials and the database was not created right now.

This is my code :

```
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($config['db']);
$capsule->bootEloquent();
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
```

Where $config['db'] contains the informations required by Eloquent :

```
$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'debug' => true,
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ],
    'db' => [
        'driver'     => 'mysql',
        'host'       => '****.mysql.db',
        'database'   => '****',
        'username'   => '****',
        'password'   => '****',
        'charset'    => 'utf8',
        'collation'  => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'     => ''
    ]
]
```

What I have to do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... I get the solution.

... Suspense ...

I have to remove spaces around the big arrows in my beautiful formatted array.

Yes. I'm gonna cry.